# Next month status in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data includes customers' statuses over months. The aim is to add a column with a next month statuses using DAX.

### Original table:

| Month | CustomerID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | D1200 | Active |
| Jan | D1300 | Sleeping |
| Feb | D1200 | Sleeping |
| Feb | D1300 | Sleeping |

### Target table:

| Month | CustomerID | Status | Next Month Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | D1200 | Active | Sleeping |
| Jan | D1300 | Sleeping | Sleeping |
| Feb | D1200 | Sleeping |  |
| Feb | D1300 | Sleeping |  |

I tried to LOOKUP a status while using Nextmonth() filter, but didn't get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified slightly your table to show the `Month` as a date format and also added two columns to demonstrate it works with different months.

### Table

| Month | CustomerID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | D1200 | Active |
| 01/01/2021 | D1300 | Sleeping |
| 01/02/2021 | D1200 | Sleeping |
| 01/02/2021 | D1300 | Sleeping |
| 01/03/2021 | D1200 | Active |
| 01/03/2021 | D1300 | Sleeping |

### Calculated Column

```
Next Month Status =
VAR SelectedCustomerID = [CustomerID]
VAR SelectedMonth = [Month]
VAR NxMonth =
    MINX ( FILTER ( 'Table', [Month] > SelectedMonth ), [Month] )
VAR StatusTable =
    FILTER ( 'Table', [CustomerID] = SelectedCustomerID && [Month] = NxMonth )
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE ( StatusTable, [Status] )
```

### Output

[image]